# Melting points of halogens

Tags: material-science

I'm helping a friend with their GCSE exams.  There was a mock question that had the melting points of all the halogens except for Chlorine.  They had to estimate the melting point of Chlorine from the other halogens.  Firstly, if Chlorine's melting point is omitted as in the test, from the graph it looks like it should be -150 $^o$C.  Do people agree?
Secondly, why is Chlorine's melting point an outlier at -101 $^o$C?

[image: Melting point of Halogens]

Comment: Why do you think it is an outlier? Why must the trend be linear with atomic number? Sure, -150C looks fine, as would -100C.

Comment: That's a valid point @JonCuster, thank you. Perhaps it was psychological framing... the previous question they asked the students was to plot the melting points (without chlorine) and add a (linear) line of best fit to them.  And then from this graph to estimate the melting point of chlorine... which my friend got wrong because they estimated -150 $^o$C.  I didn't understand how you were meant to estimate it as -101 from the graph.  Then it got me thinking why chlorine seemed to deviated from an apparent linear trend.